# Correct Variable Usage within BeautifulSoup Find() function

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How to use variables correctly in BeautifulSoup's .find() function?

Probably a simple solution but the official documentation doesn't cover it and the solution eludes me. Latest Python, stable version and latest BeautifulSoup as of yesterday.

Using the find() function seems to fail when you specify string variables as a parameter.

HTML
`<h3 id="ourId">Something</h3>`

For example:

`prodTitle = page.find("h3", {"id": "ourId"}).get_text(strip=True)`

That code works.

```
tag="h3"
attrib="id"
element="ourId"
prodTitle = page.find(tag, {attrib: element}).get_text(strip=True)
```

The above fails, any usage of a variable within Find() and the call fails with error.

*AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'*

I can try the attrib=element, hard-coding the quotations and it also fails.

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

`prodTitle = page.find(str(tag), {str(attrib): "ourId"}).get_text(strip=True)`
This code works

`prodTitle = page.find(str(tag), {str(attrib): str(element)}).get_text(strip=True)`
This code **does not** work, with or without str() or quotes passed.

Comment: Let me know if it works for you, and also the error you get if it doesn't, ty.

Comment: bettter create minimal working code which we could run because your code should work. And if you load HTML from server then use real URL so we could see if problem is in HTML on server.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Maybe you have some mistake in different place and it runs `find()` with different values than you expect. Maybe you should check values in variables using `print(tag, attrib, element)` directly before `find()`

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can use variables in bs4 (python version >= 3.6):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<h3 id="ourId">Something</h3>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

prodTitle = soup.find("h3", {"id": "ourId"}).get_text(strip=True)

tag="h3"
attrib="id"
element="ourId"

var_prodTitle = soup.find(f"{tag}", {f"{attrib}" : f"{element}"}).text.strip()
print('prodTitle', prodTitle)
print('_______________')
print('var_prodTitle', var_prodTitle)
```

Result:

```
prodTitle Something
_______________
var_prodTitle Something
```

Comment: your code works even with `soup.find(tag, {attrib: element})` - without `f-string` - so OP may have different problem.